# Multiply all values in each column of a data frame by another value based on matching column names

Tags: r, for-loop, multiple-columns

I would like to find an efficient way to multiply all values in each column in this data-frame

```
dd <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12)
```

with a value that corresponds to the name of that column on another "index" data-frame (like in either of the examples below)

```
d.1 <- data.frame(p=c("a","b","c"),q=3:5)
d.2 <- data.frame(a=3,b=4,c=5)
```

Is there a for loop way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replicate the second dataset  and do the multiplication if we use the 'd.2'

```
dd[names(d.2)] <-  dd[names(d.2)] * d.2[col(dd[names(d.2)])]
```

With 'd.1'

```
dd[as.character(d.1$p)] <-  dd[as.character(d.1$p)] * d.1$q[col(dd[d.1$p])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I provide you a `for` loop-like strategy for both cases:
Using d.1:

```
dd_new <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(dd)){
  new_col <- dd[, i] * d.1$q[which(d.1$p==names(dd)[i])]
  dd_new <- as.data.frame(cbind(dd_new, new_col))
}
dd_new
```

Using d.2:

```
dd_new <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(dd)){
  new_col <- dd[, i] * d.2[, which(names(d.2)==names(dd)[i])]
  dd_new <- as.data.frame(cbind(dd_new, new_col))
}
dd_new
```